# evil-mode visual selection copies text to clipboard automatically

Tags: evil, copy-paste, yank, clipboard

### Setup:

GUI version GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2015-07-25 on KAEL
[Compiled from EmacsW64.](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/)

Package Evil, using the latest version of Evil from MELPA

Windows 7 x64 bit.

### Situation:

Tested with empty Emacs configuration with only Evil enabled.
I copy some text from Windows application. Then I paste it into Emacs inside `normal mode` with <kbd>p</kbd>. I see the text.

Then I switch to the Windows application, select another text, copy it.
Switch back to Emacs, visually select the text, and paste inside `visual mode`. But the text inside the region will not be replaced with the text from the Windows clipboard.

This is not with the default Vim. How could I configure it, that the visually text gets replaced by the latest copy action, in this case the Windows clipboard?

Comment: Probable duplicates: [Add operating system clipboard to kill ring](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/766/add-operating-system-clipboard-to-kill-ring), [How to access os clipboard using Emacs + Evil](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12122/how-to-access-os-clipboard-using-emacs-evil).

Comment: I'm aware of both topics, but I think it's more Evil related than clipboard. The clipboard function works fine inside normal mode. And not for visual mode.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  For what it's worth, it's not Windows-specific: it also does not yank from the OS clipboard in visual state on Linux (Fedora, if it matters).

Comment: Thanks for the update, I changed the title to not be OS-specific.

Comment: Is this just a plain Evil bug? Any chance you can report it?

Comment: Actually, it seems to work *sometimes*, but I can't figure out why it works when it does, and why it does not in the majority of cases I try it.

Comment: @PythonNut, I reported it to [Evil issues tracker](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/566/evil-doesnt-paste-right-in-visual-mode). And Dan, that's weird. I had that behaviour sometimes too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no *bug* here.  Since I was also annoyed with this behavior, I just read Evil code to find out why this is happening.  So, here is a straight copy/paste of the well-commented one-liner from my Emacs configuration that fixes this issue:

```
;; Imagine the following scenario.  One wants to paste some previously copied
;; (from application other than Emacs) text to the system's clipboard in place
;; of some contiguous block of text in a buffer.  Hence, one switches to
;; `evil-visual-state' and selects the corresponding block of text to be
;; replaced.  However, one either pastes some (previously killed) text from
;; `kill-ring' or (if `kill-ring' is empty) receives the error: "Kill ring is
;; empty"; see `evil-visual-paste' and `current-kill' respectively.  The
;; reason why `current-kill' does not return the desired text from the
;; system's clipboard is because `evil-visual-update-x-selection' is being run
;; by `evil-visual-pre-command' before `evil-visual-paste'.  That is
;; `x-select-text' is being run (by `evil-visual-update-x-selection') before
;; `evil-visual-paste'.  As a result, `x-select-text' copies the selected
;; block of text to the system's clipboard as long as
;; `x-select-enable-clipboard' is non-nil (and in this scenario we assume that
;; it is).  According to the documentation of `interprogram-paste-function',
;; it should not return the text from the system's clipboard if it was last
;; provided by Emacs (e.g. with `x-select-text').  Thus, one ends up with the
;; problem described above.  To solve it, simply make
;; `evil-visual-update-x-selection' do nothing:
;; (fset 'evil-visual-update-x-selection 'ignore)
```

The last sentence is the answer to the question of how to "*configure it, that the visually text gets replaced by the latest copy action, in this case the Windows clipboard?*"

**`(fset 'evil-visual-update-x-selection 'ignore)`**

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I also enjoyed your compiled Harroogan's Emacs. Nice find, I marked your answer as the right one. As it seems, I can only upvote and mark it as right without any bounty. Which is sad, you really deserved it. :-)

Comment: Man this bug! It annoyed me to that degree that I switched back to vim just to get rid of this behaviour. I searched everywhere and also reported to the evil tracker but sadly no-one responded to my issue. Alexander, you are my hero!

Comment: NICE! This should be a default in spacemacs.

Comment: It seems sneaky how this behavior is on by default. Took me a while to realize what was happening, and the fact that there is no way to disable it via setting a variable. This workaround works well :)

Comment: This has been annoying me for way too long. Seems like an undesirable default. No?

Comment: If anyone's interested, I filed an issue: https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/1537